# HTML textarea covered with Traslucent Black Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios

I have Navigation View controller that contains web view. The top bar of Navigation View is  "Traslucent Black Navigation bar"

The web view display html that conatins "textarea" html element. I notice when user try type on the textarea, upper part of "textarea" get covred by the "Traslucent Black Navigation bar".

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the frame of your UIWebView down by 44 points (standard height of UINavigationBar)

webView.frame = CGRectMake (webView.frame.origin.x, (webView.frame.origin.y + 44), webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);